# How to prevent access to node based on custom filter/field in node?

Tags: drupal, hook, drupal-7, access-control

I am looking for a way to control access to a node (my own content type), even when it has the "published" bit set. I have a custom field (datetime) that specifies when the node should be available to visitors. How do I hook in to Drupal 7 to do that?

Best regards, Egil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on [node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_access/7), you should be able to do what you need there.

Comment: Looks like you are right, i'll give it a try and see if I can make something like that work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished a similar thing using `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_grants()`. My example is for a field within a node that restricts access on a group level, but the same concept works (more easily) for non-group content.

The description of what I did is here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36269/how-to-restrict-node-access-to-nodes-based-on-field-value/83975#83975

However, it might be easier for you to follow Node Access Example Module: https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_access_example!node_access_example.module/7

That is exactly what I modified to get my code.